# Guava - LoadingCache: capacity and performance questions

Tags: java, caching, java-8, guava

We currently have developed a logic in our Java web service that make use of Guava's LoadingCache mechanism for cache storage. We are planning to use it for detection of automated attacks. We use it the same way it was used here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts

See step 4 of the link above. Now my main question is, can this kind of setup eat up a lot of the allocated memory due to requests that are stored in the cache? we have about 25k users using our web services. With that could it possible have performance issues?

Comment: If you currently have it, did you consider profiling to check how much memory that specific feature is using and determining if that was a problem in your environment?

Comment: @BeUndead sorry i meant we are still planning to consider using it. just wanna ask those who have used it how much memory this would consume

Comment: If your only cache expiration policy is by time, then you could see your cache getting overloaded if you had a very high number of active users, each visiting once.  (That implementation is also not thread-safe...)

Comment: You could use a fixed cost data structure, like a 4-bit count-min sketch, to probabilistically estimate the frequency. Then reset the sketch periodically, e.g. using `Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration`. Then size the sketch to handle a reasonable number of concurrent users in the time window.